# replace text function not working in explorer

Tags: javascript, text, replace

I have a js replace function to replace text next to two radio buttons on a pre set form.

Script is as follows.

```
document.body.innerHTML=document.body.innerHTML.replace("Payment by <b>Moneybookers</b> 
e-wallet<br>","");

document.body.innerHTML=document.body.innerHTML.replace("Maestro, Visa and other credit/debit cards by <b>Moneybookers</b>","Pago con Diners Club, Mastercard o Visa");}onload=x;
```

The script works fine in Chrome and Firefox, however, the script is not actioned in Explorer.

I believe it has something to do with there being , / - within the text I am replacing? When I use the function to replace text with no , / - in the text - it works fine in explorer, however, for example when I try to replace text.. - "Maestro, Visa and other credit/debit cards by Moneybookers" this does not work in explorer.. I'm assuming because of the coma and forward slash. Honestly I've tried everything but just can not get this to work. Any help would be greatly appreciated!!

Comment: If you look at the JavaScript console in the browser, you'll see a syntax error. So that would be where to start. You should see a little yellow **!** in the left-hand side of the status bar, which if you click it shows you the error.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure whether it's related (I'm a Mac user without IE) but you shouldn't use multiline strings. Use `\n` instead.

Comment: Thanks Tom, I'll be honest Im a real novice, how would I adapt my script to us \n instead..? Many thanks!

Comment: `document.body.innerHTML=document.body.innerHTML.replace("Payment by <b>Moneybookers</b>\ne-wallet<br>","");`

Answer (score 1):

What is returned by innerHTML varies from one browser to an other, because there is no standard about it (the content will be the same, but the way it's displayed can be different). Doing replace like that is likely to fail on some browser. You should just take an other approach to do your replace.

A better approach would be to wrap the text you want to replace with a `span`, this way you can more easily target the content you want to replace.

```
<span id="thatFirstThing">Payment by <b>Moneybookers</b>e-wallet<br></span>
```

An after you can do

```
document.getElementById("thatFirstThing").innerHTML = "";
```

P.S.: Doing innerHTML replace on the body also has a huge side-effect. Since you are replacing the content of your hole page. All the event handler that where bind on your page will disappear.

Edit: If you can't modify the HTML page, it's a little bit more tricky, because the DOM is not well adapted to do such thing. What you could do is to target parent element by navigating through the DOM with [`document.getElementById`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/document.getElementById) and [`childNodes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/childNodes). And once you have your parent element just write the new content you want, without doing replace.

In the end it would look something like this :

```
 document.getElementById("someSection").childNodes[0].childNodes[1].childNodes[0].innerHTML = "";
```

Comment: *"What is returned by innerHTML varies from one browser to an other..."* True, but irrelevant, as the OP is *setting* the property, not reading it. *"...because there is no standard about it..."* It's in the process of [being standardized as part of HTML5](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/apis-in-html-documents.html#innerhtml).

Comment: @T.J.Crowder He both read and the set the value of `document.body.innerHTML`, what do you mean by he's not reading it ?

Comment: hey, Thanks so much for looking at this. Im just new to this whole js thing. Could you kindly advise how I should amend this onto the script, truth is someone else wrote this for me.... Should I put the span script before my script..? and where you have ''thatfirstthing'' soo sorry - what do I put in there..? Thanks so much!!

Comment: @HoLyVieR: Somehow I managed to miss that he was reading it (but there it is, plain as day). Doh! :-) Still, though, the bigger issue would be the syntax error.

Comment: @LEOPM Well for the HTML part, you have to edit the content of the page. Where you have the `Payment by <b>Moneybookers</b>` (or the code that output it) in your page, that's where you add a `span` around the text. The `thatFirstThing` is just an example of an id you can give to that span. It can be anything, you just have to give it a name and reuse that name to access it in your javascript code.

Comment: Hey HoLyVieR, problem I have there is I can not edit the HTML content. You see its a third party shopping cart page, on this page are preset payment options next to a radio button form. The only power to edit I have is 255 characters of html that can be entered to amend what shows on this screen, I can source to a js file which means I can use more characters.